# What Does the Bible Say About Cremation?

Tags: bible, cremation

In Bible times, only people in God’s disfavor were burned after death.
[image]

Comment: VTC on dup: [According to the Bible, is cremation an acceptable Christian practice?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/according-to-the-bible-is-cremation-an-acceptable-christian-practice). Additional good article covering the topic: [The FAQs: What Christians Should Know About Cremation](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/the-faqs-what-christians-should-know-about-cremation/). Basically, Biblical times vs. modern times see cremation very differently. In general as long as the Christians who choose cremation still believe in the resurrection of the body, it's okay.

Comment: In some circles within Christendom - cremation is not acceptable.

Comment: The other side would say that the resurrection will reverse everything that happens to our bodies, and that we should be good stewards with our resources. In some places today burial plots are *very* expensive.

Comment: @curiousdannii I bought my own burial plot (UK) a few years ago for £350. It is in a very pleasant cemetery with landscaped gardens.

Comment: @NigelJ You're lucky then. The closest cemetery to me (in my surburban Australian neighbourhood) has plots that cost almost 5000AUD. I assume plots in rural cemeteries would be much cheaper.